# Allow Laravel routes to specify `withTrashed` despite explicit model bindings

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, soft-delete

### Background

In my Laravel application, I have models `Organization`, `Region`, and `Location`, which all have a polymorphic relationship to the `User` model via an `Assignment` model. (An `Assignment` is a three-way relationship between `User`, `Role`, and one of the other three entities, but that is not strictly relevant to the problem here.)

I wanted to add a `showUsers` method to each of the controllers for the other three models that gets all of the users associated with that entity. To avoid copy-pasting the same code in all three controllers, I created a `trait` like this:

```php
use App\Http\Resources\UserSimpleWithRoleResource;
use App\Models\Assignment;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

trait GetsRelatedUsers
{
    function listUsers(Model $model)
    {
        // Thanks to explicit model binding,
        // `$model` can be any supported model.

        $assignments = Assignment::with(['user:id,given_name,surname', 'role:id,name,display_order'])
            ->has('user') // prevents assignments for soft-deleted users from showing up
            ->atPlace($model) // a scope that also adds other conditions based on the provided model
            ->get();

        return UserSimpleWithRoleResource::collection($assignments);
    }
}
```

In order to resolve the `Model $model` value from the route, I need to have explicit model bindings in my `RouteServiceProvider`'s `boot` method, like this:

```php
Route::model('location', Location::class);
Route::model('region', Region::class);
Route::model('organization', Organization::class);
```

### Problem

In my routes file, I have the three controllers for `Organization`, `Region`, and `Location` set up to allow viewing and editing soft-deleted models like this:

```php
Route::apiResource('organizations', \App\Http\Api\Organizations\Controller::class)->withTrashed(['show', 'update']);
Route::apiResource('regions', \App\Http\Api\Regions\Controller::class)->withTrashed(['show', 'update']);
Route::apiResource('locations', \App\Http\Api\Locations\Controller::class)->withTrashed(['show', 'update']);
```

Before I added the explicit model binding, the built-in implicit model binding would check the route for the presence of the `withTrashed` option, and would change the model resolver to include trashed items. However, explicit bindings don't do this check.

Short of completely reimplementing the check for `$route->allowsTrashedBindings()` in my explicit model bindings, is there a nice way to implement this so that some routes can include trashed items and others cannot?

Comment: Can you try to add model scope and then extend the said model to your 3 models in need instead of trait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the best I've been able to come up with so far, though I'm not really happy with it:

```php
Route::bind('location', function ($id, RouteDefintion $route) {
    return Location::query()
        ->when($route->allowsTrashedBindings(), function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        })
        ->findOrFail($id);
});

Route::bind('region', function ($id, RouteDefintion $route) {
    return Region::query()
        ->when($route->allowsTrashedBindings(), function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        })
        ->findOrFail($id);
});

Route::bind('organization', function ($id, RouteDefintion $route) {
    return Organization::query()
        ->when($route->allowsTrashedBindings(), function ($query) {
            $query->withTrashed();
        })
        ->findOrFail($id);
});
```

Notes:

- `RouteDefinition` is `use Illuminate\Routing\Route as RouteDefintion;` because `Route` is already used by the router facade.
- The `$route` parameter in the callback function is undocumented; I found it by looking through the framework source.
- I could probably simplify this by making a function that takes a model class so that I don't have to repeat it three times, but I really want to see if there's a more elegant answer first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it like this in RouteServiceProvider.
Where one name for model binding is used for routes where you do want softdeletes in the model binding, and one without softdeletes in the model binding.

```php
Route::bind('location', function ($value) {
    return Location::where('id', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
Route::bind('location-with-trashed', function ($value) {
    return Location::withTrashed()->where('id', $value)->firstOrFail();
});
```

Though you need to test if this works.

See here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/43008#issuecomment-1170673827

Comment: That doesn't do what I want. That will always include trashed models but there are some routes for which I do not want them. I want to use the route options whether to include trashed models or not.

Comment: Yeah, but that's how explicit model binding works. You define how that model is bound to all routes using that modelbinding under that name. If you don't want that you either have to use implicit binding, roll your own binding resolvers, or don't use model binding on routes where you want to retrieve softdeletes.
Or you define a model binding with a name `locationWithtrashed` or something that you use to retrieve softdeletes, and a different name for bindings without. That should work, though I haven't tested it.